# wordpress - images & files uploading issue -(jQuery?)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm using the eMember plugin on my website, it should display a profile image uploader on the edit profile page. There is no uploader, I can see only profile image. 
I find this error in console, but I'm not sure what it means. 
Can anyone help me?

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).validationEngine is not a
>   function(anonymous function) @
>   ?emember_load_js=profile&id=wp_emember_profileUpdateForm:65x.Callbacks.l
>   @ jquery.min.js:4x.Callbacks.c.fireWith @
>   jquery.min.js:4x.extend.ready @ jquery.min.js:4S @ jquery.min.js:4
>   (index):259 WPP: OK. Execution time: 0.003635 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).**validationEngine is not a function**

It seems that the import of the [validation engine plugin](https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine) wasn't made (it's a jQuery plugin for validating forms).

You can try to manually import it by downloading the zip from:
https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine/archive/master.zip

And then place these lines in the main js file or in the file that contains that form (place them after the jQuery line and check if the `src` points to the files you downloaded):

```
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.validationEngine.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Place this one near the other CSS imports as well:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/validationEngine.jquery.css" type="text/css"/>
```

However, if you really think it's caused by the eMember plugin, I think the authors may help you better (since it's a paid plugin and they seem to [answer customers in this page](https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/wordpress-emember-easy-to-use-wordpress-membership-plugin-1706) or even through [their contact page](http://support.tipsandtricks-hq.com/contact)).

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it didn't work. I don't think that it's caused by the eMember plugin. It's more likely my mistake. I posted my question at eMember customer's forum, waiting for an answer, but I don't think they will help if problem isn't caused by eMember.

Comment: @DorotaKolasińska if you import those javascript files, that error should be gone from the console. You can recheck the console after it, just to see if there's a new error or something else is happening...

Comment: that's exactly what I did. And I rechecked in the console - it was 10x more errors than before import those files.

Comment: @DorotaKolasińska wow... so something is very wrong. If you can edit your question with the new errors, I can take a look... One thing it usually worked for me a while ago was to disable any wordpress plugins that may cause problems... I know, lots of things will not be there anymore, but at least you know which plugin is causing all the trouble.

Comment: I've solved my problem. eMember support, as I expected, answered me shortly, that it's not their plugin causing  an error, but some other plugin. Since I am less than one year expirienced in coding, it would be much more probably, that it's not any plugin, but created by me from scratch theme. And It was :) I fixed bug in my theme and everything works now.